# Multispectral photography and biology

Tags: color, photography

I recently made a post to the Photography site at StackExchange and I was told this might be a better forum.

My original post can be found [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/134639/cameras-with-more-than-3-color-channelsa-ideally-12-and-digital-formatting/134647#134647). From a high level I have a friend who is beginning a research project and I suggested possibly using ultraviolet light to identify individual specimens of fish similar to what is done [here](https://www.livescience.com/9853-fish-uv-light-distinguish-faces.html).

The question I asked there had to do with using multispectral images to try and mimic mantis shrimp vision to see if there was any biological signal that is invisible to the human eye. The hope would be to filter out individual wavelengths to see if there are 'outlines' that are visible to the shrimp but invisible to humans and parse out any potential signals.

I found [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7929508/) discussing a proof of concept that mimics this vision but I was also curious to see if there has been any research done already to take multispectral imaging to match color hues that are visible to certain species that are not visible to humans. I've been able to find to some resources for multispectral image data files but I have not been able to find much research done in a context similar to what is described above, i.e. trying to capture images that would be visible to certain animals but invisible to humans.

Does anyone here have any good resources or leads to investigate work that's already been done?

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: You kind of got your answer there; It's doable and it's being done. Is this actually something you want to do or are you just curious? Do you have the funds to do this? Are you ready to carry out this research and with whom would you do it? Seems to me you need to speak with the folks who are actually doing this with something fairly concrete in mind, but that's only one opinion.

Comment: Say it's curiously for now but it could change into something actionable later.

I'm not actively involved in research at the moment but I could be doing some consulting and assistance for one particular project. It would almost certainly not use be using multispectral photography. After reading a bit deeper about photography and having it brought to my attention that cameras can capture light that would match frequencies certain animal eyes are attuned to but not human I was hoping to check in and see if anyone has good resources on work that's been done. I hope you can forgive the naivety.

Comment: It's not naivety at all nor is it a bad question (I upvoted it); lots of people are just genuinely curious about Biology, and that you've done some searching yourself says a lot that's positive. My thoughts (fwiw) I'm not familiar with anyone here doing that kind of research, or having a deep interest in it. I hope someone answers, but I kinda doubt anyone will, because we - well, most of us - have jobs, and mere curiosity questions get left behind because searches take time. If there's someone who's knowledgeable or excited about the field, you'll get an answer. If you don't, you'll know why.

Comment: Having said that, there are some neurobiologists here who might be able to answer, and one of them seems particularly interested in sight, so who knows? In advising you to talk to those who are already doing this, if it's just curiosity, you may or may not get an answer. If it were a collaboration you wanted to do, you would be taken more seriously. (When I was in research, it was pretty cut-throat, and people kept their methods close to their chests, but that was ages ago.) Also, people at conferences/profs are generally more generous and helpful. Sorry I can't help; my field is medicine.

Comment: *neuroscientists, duh.

Comment: It seems like there are two pretty different things here; one is imaging into the UV (or infrared) relative to human vision; those things are pretty common by themselves for various purposes. Then there's oversampling the visual range, which doesn't actually reveal any "new" or invisible colors as in new wavelengths, but does add to the ability to resolve similar wavelengths as clearly distinct, which might help draw out certain patterns.